# Center two elements with CSS

Tags: css, html

How am I able to center vertically both the form and the and div next to it? I need to be able to scroll if the container of both is smaller than the inner content height space.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer_1">
  <div id="inner_1">
    <form id="form">
      <input/>
      <input/>
    </form>
    <div id="login-request">
      If you do not have a login,
      <span>touch here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#outer_1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

#inner_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#form {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#login-request {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mluis/4vtf5cn6/3/).

Comment: may need to display: table-cell; Back on the display: inline-block; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, the form and the message both are horizontally and vertical center aligned, look at it in
http://jsfiddle.net/4vtf5cn6/10/

```
<div id="outer_1">
  <div id="inner_1">
    <form id="form">
      <input/>
      <input/>
      <div id="login-request" class="login-request-alert">
        If you do not have a Travelport Mobile Agent login,
        <span class="urlink">touch here</span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#outer_1{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
#inner_1{
    padding-top:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#form{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
#login-request{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just fix this with a `float:left` on both divs?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vtf5cn6/6/

Added lines are marked with `**`, so don't just copy the below code ;)

```css
#outer_1{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;

}

#inner_1{
    **padding-top:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#form{
    display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   **float:left;
}
#login-request{
    display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   **float:left;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: both input and login-request don't to appear on the center of the red square

Comment: They do with me, as you can see in the result image.

Comment: The center of the red square should be on the center point horizontally and vertically

Comment: Well, you don't mention that in your question. You ask us about how to get both divs centered in the red div.

Answer (score 0):

try this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4vtf5cn6/11/)

```css
#form{
    display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
#login-request{
    display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: The "inlinne" is also still in your demo :)

Comment: both input and login-request don't to appear on the center of the red square

Answer (score 0):

An option could be percentage values for `margin-top` property of CSS rule. For example:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
.child {
  /* Center horizontally */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  /* Center vertically */
  margin-top: 50%;
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a `<div>`, which encloses the `#form` and the `#login-request`. Like:

```
<div id="outer_1">
    <div id="inner_1">
        <div id="enclose">
            <form id="form">
                <input/>
                <input/>
            </form>
            <div id="login-request" >
                If you do not have a login,
                <span>touch here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the CSS:

```css
#enclose {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and style the `#form` and the `#login-request` as you need it

Comment: can't get both divs to apear vertically aligned. inputs and the login-request still appear one right next to other horizontally

Comment: give the #eclose the width, which you need.
To the #form and #login-request add in the css: position: relative; width: 100%;